# Javascript Regex check if URL contains one word AND does NOT contain another

Tags: javascript, regex, url, location, href

How can one check a url if it contains a specific word, but also check to see if it doesn't contain a word?  Its better if I try and display an example:

Do something if the word '**pan**' is in the URL, however do NOT do anything when the word '**panini**' is in the url:

```
if (/pan/.test(self.location.href) && (/panini/.test(self.location.href) == null)  {...}
```

The above first part works fine, but with the second panini part added it of course will not work, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Thanks now Im hungry *looks for panini*

Comment: I don't see how the code you quote will not do what you describe. Please give an example where it does something different from what you want.

Comment: Because it returns false, not null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) returns a bool, so just use the `!` operator:

```
if (/pan/.test(self.location.href) && !(/panini/.test(self.location.href))  {...}
```

This could be simplified to use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) (should be faster):

```
if (self.location.href.indexOf("pan") > -1 && self.location.href.indexOf("panini") == -1)
{...}
```

Additionally, a regex testing for a word can use a word boundary, `\b`:

```
/\bpan\b/.test(self.location.href)
//Will match "pan", "pan and food", but not "panini"
```

Comment: Dang, you were quicker on the draw! :)

Comment: @ToddN Can you try it again? I missed a `)`.

Comment: ahh thank you!  So by adding an exclamation point `!` it will basically not pull the if statement with the word panini in it?

Comment: This was tested and worked for multiple words I did not want, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript's `indexOf` might solve your problem.

```
var h=location.href;
if (h.indexOf("pan")>-1 && h.indexOf("panini")==-1) // do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `indexOf` property as follows:

```
url = window.location.href;
if ((url.indexOf("pan") >= 0) && (url.indexOf("panini") < 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myurl = self.location.href;
if (myurl.indexOf("pan") != -1) && (myurl.indexOf("panini") == -1)
{
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use negative lookahead, which JS supports in all major browsers.

```
if ((/pan(?!ini)/).test(myurl)) {
```

The `/pan(?!ini)/` regex matches any "pan" not followed by "ini".